# Higher version of 3x3 lemma

Tags: homotopy-theory, triangulated-categories

Consider a category of complexes over some additive category, and suppose we have a square that commutes up to homotopy. Then, one can consider mapping cones over all edges of the square, and obtain a 3x3 diagram where all faces commute up to homotopy (this is the classical 3x3 lemma in triangulated categories).

Now my intuition is that given a cube where each face commutes up to homotopy, and there is a higher homotopy filling the cube, then one should also be able to complete it in a 3x3x3 diagram where each face commute up to homotopy. This should hold in general for higher dimensional cubes also. I think I read that something of this flavor is proven in "Munson and Volic, Cubical homotopy theory", but I'm not sure and I was wondering if there exists a reference where it would be proven in the particular case of the category of complexes ? Or if it is wrong and I'm missing something ?

Comment: A nice way to get all such lemmas is to use (homotopy) left/right Kan extensions. Extend your diagram one little bit at a time- when you want to add in zeroes, use right Kan extensions, and when you want to add in cofibers, use left Kan extensions. To see this trick in action, you can check out the proof of the octahedral axiom for stable infinity categories given in Higher Algebra (Theorem 1.1.2.14)